# executing perl script using python

Tags: python-3.x

i have a perl script 'ProcessServerData.pl' in 'C:\Users\Gurpreet Singh\Desktop\Amar_AG\KA03MM7155' and wish to run it through python program present in 'C:\Users\Gurpreet Singh\Desktop\Amar_AG'. What should my python program be?